# Angular RouteParams send ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ngroute

I am trying to send an ID through to a controller using $routeParams via a factory but it is not working.

My $routeProvider:

```
.when('/event/:eventId', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/event_detail.html',
    controller  : 'eventPageCtrl'
});
```

My factory:

```
myApp.factory('eventRepo', ['$http', function($http) {

    var urlBase = 'php/api.php';
    var eventRepo = {};

    eventRepo.getEvent = function (id) {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '?eventID=' + id);
    };

    return eventRepo;

}]);
```

My Controller:

```
myApp.controller('eventPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'eventRepo', 
        function ($scope, $routeParams, eventRepo) {

        $scope.getEvent = function (id) {
            eventRepo.getEvent($routeParams.eventId)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.eventsDetail = data;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Error retrieving event! ' + error.message;
            });
        };  

}]);
```

When handling $http.get() inside the controller and not with the factory it works fine so I think I am not passing my $routeParams correctly?  Perhaps this line is causing the issue `eventRepo.getEvent($routeParams.eventId)`?

This works currently, but trying to use $http.get() outside the controller:

```
myApp.controller('eventPageCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

      $http.get("php/api.php?eventID="+$routeParams.eventId).success(function(data){
            $scope.eventsDetail = data;
           });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to console.log `$routeParams.eventId` in `$scope.getEvent`?

Comment: What actually isn't working?  Is it passing `undefined`?  What triggers the `$scope.getEvent` function?

Comment: Your api.php receives `eventID` or `eventId`?

Answer (score 0):

how about using `resolve` in your routeProver and returning the `eventId` and then injecting it in the `controller` .. example :

$routeProvider:

```
.when('/event/:eventId', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/event_detail.html',
        controller  : 'eventPageCtrl',
        resolve : {
                    eventId: function($route, $location) {
                        var eventId = $route.current.params.eventId;
                        return eventId;
    });
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('eventPageCtrl', ['$scope', 'eventId', 'eventRepo', 
        function ($scope, eventId, eventRepo) {   //add it as a dependency

        $scope.eventId = eventId;   //you can check this to see if its being assigned 
        $scope.getEvent = function (eventId) {     //Edit: eventId added here
            eventRepo.getEvent(eventId)            //Edit: eventId passed 
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.eventsDetail = data;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Error retrieving event! ' + error.message;
            });
        };  

}]);
```